# How can I solve an undefined BASE_URI?

Tags: php, .htaccess, uri, router

I am working on a project using PHP and routers.
I have this error message.

```
Notice: Undefined index: BASE_URI in C:\laragon\www\myproject\public\index.php on line 30
Notice: Undefined index: BASE_URI in C:\laragon\www\myproject\app\Controllers\MainController.php on line 39
```

Here is line 39 :

> ```
>     `$viewVars['baseURL'] = $_SERVER['BASE_URI'];`
> ```

```
I also have a .htaccess file :
RewriteEngine On

# dynamically setup base URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE_URI:%1]

# redirect every request to index.php
# and give the relative URL in "_url" GET param
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Where can I define my BASE_URI ?
Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located? What is the URL you are requesting? And what is the document root directory?